# How to retrieve all public methods from *.dll

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, public-method

I have *.dll written with C# and I need to get list of all public methods or classes contained in that *.dll. Is there some way to do it programmatically with C#?

Answer (score 18):

Yes use [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to extract all of the types, and then use reflection on each type to iterate the public methods.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("...");
Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (!type.IsPublic)
    {
        continue;
    }

    MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public
                                          |BindingFlags.Instance
                                          |BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);
    foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name+"."+member.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var assembly = // grab assembly
var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

foreach (var type in types) {
    var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
}
```

GetExportedTypes will return all public types in the assembly. You also didn't specify whether you wanted just instance methods, static methods or both.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("...") method is now deprecated, use LoadFile() method instead.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile("filename.dll");
        Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            if (!type.IsPublic)
            {
                continue;
            }

            MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMethods();
            foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name + "." + member.Name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use System.Net.Reflection. Reflection classes let you query the metadata of types of a DLL at run time.

Something like `this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes();`